# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Mixpanel bindings

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mixpanel

I'm trying to integrate Mixpanel into my Xamarin.Android project.
But when I'm calling `Com.Mixpanel.Android.Mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.GetInstance()`, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception is thrown with message *com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics/MixpanelAPI*.

I've just built MixpanelAPI.jar, then created "Android Java Bindings Library" project, added jar as InputJar (also tried EmbeddedJar), then built dll and imported it into my project.

`jar tf MixpanelAPI.jar` shows all classes, `javap` shows valid class interfaces.
Assembly Browser also shows all classes. But when it comes to `class_ref` `get`, exception is thrown.

I can't get what I am doing wrong.

Stacktrace:

> ```
> [MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError' was thrown.
>  [MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (string) [0x00087] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.0-branch/b76e8ec4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:287
>  [MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (string,intptr&) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.0-branch/b76e8ec4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:300
>  [MonoDroid] at Com.Mixpanel.Android.Mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.get_class_ref () [0x00000] in /path/to/mixpanel/bindings/project/Mixpanel/Mixpanel/obj/Release/generated/src/Com.Mixpanel.Android.Mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.cs:1047
>  [MonoDroid] at Com.Mixpanel.Android.Mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.GetInstance (Android.Content.Context,string) [0x00014] in /path/to/mixpanel/bindings/project/Mixpanel/Mixpanel/obj/Release/generated/src/Com.Mixpanel.Android.Mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.cs:1199
> ```

[Mixpanel bindings (65 KB)](http://rghost.net/49120296) and
[Test project for bindings (7 KB)](http://rghost.net/49120301)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project and its intermeadiate project if any. Go to Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries-> The removed androied dependecies and android private libraries. Clean projects. It should remove classDefNotFound exception.

Comment: What IDE are you talking about?

Comment: Eclipse. Which one you are using?

Comment: Xamarin studio.  It's C#.  Not java.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the lib/jar you have generated is possibly referencing a class which is now not in scope. 
I would suggest revisiting the binding project to ensure that everything is being referenced correctly.

Comment: According to exception message, it can't find `MixpanelAPI`, but `$ javap -classpath MixpanelAPI.jar com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI` shows class interface. Assembly Browser shows C# interface too.